# How to make a mobile's Call function using asp.net in mobile web application

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-mobile, call

I am developing a mobile web application in asp.net.

I have a button in menu for "call to support" and my requirement is that if anybody click on it than it should call the Calling functionality of mobile.

I am wondering that how can i do this. If you have any idea that please share with me. I need help!!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work. Using a tel protocol in the link i.e.

```
<a href="tel://012345" >Call support</a>
```

Comment: ohhh.. its great.. working fine for me in iphone.. :) thanks alot @crab